# Need help in SQL join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g, inner-join

I have two tables as below:

Table: **Employee**

```
employeeid  code_one    code_two
101          17112       17112
102          17113       17112
103          17114       17112
104          17115       16800
106          17116       17112
107          17117       18000
108          17118       17112
```

Table: **Code**

```
codeid  codename
17112   200TS
17113   400TS
17114   100TS
17115   500TS
17116   620TS
17117   899TS
17118   900TS
16800   888TS
18000   912TS
```

I need a output like:
**output**

```
employeeid  code_one    code_two
101         200TS       200TS
102         400TS       200TS
103         100TS       200TS
104         500TS       888TS
106         620TS       200TS
107         899TS       912TS
108         900TS       200TS
```

I need to map code id's from employee table with their corrsponding code names from code table. Please help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to join the tables properly.

**Table Data**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM employee;

EMPLOYEEID   CODE_ONE   CODE_TWO
---------- ---------- ----------
       101      17112      17112
       102      17113      17112
       103      17114      17112
       104      17115      16800
       106      17116      17112
       107      17117      18000
       108      17118      17112

7 rows selected.

SQL> SELECT * FROM code;

    CODEID CODENAME
---------- --------
     17112 200TS
     17113 400TS
     17114 100TS
     17115 500TS
     17116 620TS
     17117 899TS
     17118 900TS
     16800 888TS
     18000 912TS

9 rows selected.
```

**Query**

Using **Oracle** join syntax:

```
SQL> column code_one format a8
SQL> column code_two format a8
SQL> SELECT E.employeeid,
  2    C1.codename AS code_one,
  3    C2.codename AS code_two
  4  FROM Employee e,
  5    code c1,
  6    code c2
  7  WHERE E.code_one = c1.codeid
  8  AND E.code_two   = c2.codeid
  9  /

EMPLOYEEID CODE_ONE CODE_TWO
---------- -------- --------
       108 900TS    200TS
       106 620TS    200TS
       103 100TS    200TS
       102 400TS    200TS
       101 200TS    200TS
       104 500TS    888TS
       107 899TS    912TS

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Using **ANSI** join syntax:

```
SQL> SELECT E.employeeid,
  2    C1.codename AS code_one,
  3    C2.codename AS code_two
  4  FROM Employee e
  5  INNER JOIN code c1
  6  ON E.code_one = c1.codeid
  7  INNER JOIN code c2
  8  ON E.code_two = c2.codeid
  9  /

EMPLOYEEID CODE_ONE CODE_TWO
---------- -------- --------
       108 900TS    200TS
       106 620TS    200TS
       103 100TS    200TS
       102 400TS    200TS
       101 200TS    200TS
       104 500TS    888TS
       107 899TS    912TS

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: **Never** suggest *old style comma separated join* to anyone. Always use proper **INNER JOIN** syntax

Comment: @Fireblade Well, it's an old habit while working with Oracle databases. Anyway, added the ANSI syntax, thanks.

Comment: I need to have a query for mssql server please.

Comment: @curiousboy Then why did you tag `oracle`? And by the way, the NASI syntax should work with `sql server` too. Did you try?

Comment: @downvoter May I know the reason to downvote? The solution is exactly what OP wants.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `join` the `code` table twice.

```
SELECT E.employeeid,
       C.codename  AS code_one,
       C1.codename AS code_two
FROM   Employee E
       INNER JOIN Code C
               ON E.code_one = c.code
       INNER JOIN Code c1
               ON E.code_two = c.code
```

Comment: It is syntactically incorrect in Oracle. `AS` keyword is not used for table aliasing.